# Given the second derivatives of y and x wrt. a third variable, what is the second derivative of y wrt. x?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I understand that if ${dy\over dt}$ and ${dx\over dt}$ are known, then ${dy\over dx}={{dy\over dt}\over {dx\over dt}}$ based on this logic:

[y' wrt x in terms of y' wrt t and x' wrt t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYWAQ.png)

I'm wondering how this relates to second derivatives:

If ${d^2y\over dt^2}$ and ${d^2x\over dt^2}$ are known, what is ${d^2y\over dx^2}$?

I tried using the same method as the one above, but got stuck at this step:

[y'' wrt. x in terms of y'' wrt. t and x'' wrt. t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvhoD.png)

My guess is that the above expression is the same as ${{d^2y\over dt^2}\over {d^2x\over dt^2}}$. If this is the case, is the result for third derivatives ${d^3y\over dx^3}={{d^3y\over dt^3}\over {d^3x\over dt^3}}$, and so on?

I tried googling it but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is absolutely wrong.

Chain rule means first differentiate that term in respect of whatever extra variable you have then multiply it with derivative of the that variable with respect to x

Applied chain rule

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt} * \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

Differentiate it again

You get $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\frac{dy}{dt}}{({\frac{dx}{dt}})^2}*{\frac{dt}{dx}}$$

Answer (score -1):

We need to apply chain rule.

$$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac {d}{dx}(\frac {dy}{dx})=$$

$$ \frac {d}{dx}(\frac {y'}{x'})=$$

Use quotient rule on the top and simplify to get

$$\frac { \frac {d}{dt}(\frac {y'}{x'})}{dx/{dt}}= \frac { y''x'-x''y'}
   {(x')^2 (x')  }=$$

$$\frac{ y''x'-x''y'}{(x')^3}$$

where $x',y',x'',y'',x'''$ are derivatives with rsepect to $t$.

Comment: Completely wrong !!!!!!!!

Comment: @HarshitGupta  Your answer and mine are the same. What is wrong with my answer.?

Comment: Your denominator contains third derivative.That's absolutely absurd.While mine contains first derivative cubed

Comment: @HarshitGupta You have $\frac {dt}{dx} $ multiplied which is the same as having divided by $\frac {dx}{dt}$  so the results are the same.

Comment: Yeah so it should be $ (x')^3$ not x'''

Comment: And how can second derivative contains third derivative

Comment: @HarshitGupta Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I fixed it.